# Get all screens different DPI in WPF?

Tags: wpf, highdpi

In a multi monitor enviroment, how can I find all screens and their DPI (which might not be the same)?

My users logs on from home via Remote Desktop and many of them have Surface Book which has high DPI and then a second screen with default DPI (96).

I know of the "PresentationSource.FromVisual", but that does not work for getting DPI for all screens.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple actually.

a calculation using these values

```
screen.Bounds.Width;
screen.Bounds.Height;
screen.Bounds.Size;
```

combined with getting screens using `Screen.AllScreens` (System.Windows.Forms [assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens?view=netframework-4.7.2))

and you're done.

Comment: How would you calculate DPI using these values?

Comment: AFAIK, the width/height/size have no information about DPI so doesn't seem to be an answer to the question.